# On Multiple Components the same Model/Data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

i am trying to code a simple dashboard with React, node and mongo.
Register and Login works well:)

So now i want to display the User Name on the Topbar with his Picture. I load the data (name and picture url) in the Topbar component via Ajax from the Server. So right, soo good.

Soo, but i need User Data for a lot of other components. (Friends, Notifications and soo soon)  i can't in every componente an ajax call to my server make or? But i don't understand how to do this.

I need Data from the same Model in many different components.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the context api or redux to create a 'global' store and access any data in it from anywhere down or up the component hierarchy without having to pass props down each level. In redux you can access any piece of this global state with the connect hoc.

[More on redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/store)

[More on context api](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

[Comparison of the two](https://daveceddia.com/context-api-vs-redux/)